# What is the expected date for the first Starship 20km test flight?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship

What is the expected date for the first Starship test flight which is aiming for 20km flight? Is there any news about it?

Initially, it was 11th October but after September 27 presentation it is unclear now when it will happen?

Answer (score 3):

During the Q&A after the September 2019 updated, one of the media reporters asked Elon what the time line was for the test.
He replied saying in 1 to 2 months to do the 20km flight with mark 1. I don't remember seeing October 11 anywhere. There seems to be no paperwork that's is public yet about any kind of hop. They will have to file a Temporary Flight Restriction (TFR) with the FAA before hand. So I would keep an eye on that for when you see one popup around Brownsville.
https://tfr.faa.gov/tfr2/list.html

Comment: Actually I saw in a post that they have taken government's approval for October something between (11-13) that's why I thought.

Comment: I'm sure there are talks already, these take time. I just haven't seen any public filings with the FAA yet. Once you see that, that's when a real date will be seen.

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur A lot of articles were [posted on 10/11](https://spaceflightnow.com/2019/10/11/spacexs-next-launch-to-mark-another-incremental-step-in-rocket-reusability/), that could be the confusion?

Comment: It's very easy to get confused nowadays with the amount of planned and upcoming launches. Like with the FAA filing for the Dragon inflight abort, people thinking it was for starship. SpaceX is both very private and public about things which is confusing.